# Give A#Logo a background color while using a transparent sprite?

Tags: html, css, background, sprite, graphical-logo

I'm currently using an image sprite as my logo, so when you hover over the logo, it turns red.
For the HTML I set it up this way:

```
<div id="logo-wrap">
  <a id="logo" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"></a>
</div>
         ​
```

I aimed to setting the background color to `#000` by adding the "logo-wrap" div, but nothing changes. However, if I add `background: #000 url(imageurl);` to **`A#logo`** the background then appears.

Adding color to the logo itself won't allow me to add padding to the black background. It messes up the whole "sprite" idea.

I'm trying to find a way to have a separate background for the logo and add padding about 10px.

Is this possible? Or will I have to change the HTML and CSS to accomplish this?

**Fiddle**//

http://jsfiddle.net/dFmQK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I think this is what you are going for.

Use this for your CSS

```
    #logo-wrap { background: #123; width:176px; height:61px; padding: 10px;}
    A#logo {     width:176px; height:61px; background: url(http://keihead.com/test/images/trd_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat; position:relative; float: left;}
    A#logo:hover { background-position: 0 -61px;   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dFmQK/1/

Comment: Very simple! For some reason I just never thought to add the height and width :( Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: No problem. It took me a second to catch it too.